# Complexity of creating list with concat operator in python

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

I am starting to learn about data structures+algorithms, and I have encountered an issue. Here is the function I am testing:

```
def create_list_with_concat(n):
    l = []
    for i in range(n):
        l = l + [i]
```

Here is my thought process:
I know that the concat operator is `O(k)` where `k` is the size of the list being added to the original list. Since the size of `k` is always `1` in this case because we are adding one character lists at a time, the concat operation takes `1` step. Since the loop iterates `n` times, the algorithm will perform `n` steps - doing `1` step per iteration. Therefore, the algorithm's time complexity would be `O(n)`. The algorithm's actual execution time would look something like `T(n) = dn` where `d` is the time it takes to perform the concatenation. For such a function, I would expect the following to be true: when you increase the input size by 10 times, the output (execution time) would increase by 10 times since:

`(x, dx) --> (10x, 10dx) --> 10dx/dx = 10`

However, when I actually test out the algorithm on real values and time the executions, this does not seem to be happening. Instead, when I increase the input size by 10 times, the output (execution time) increases by 100 times, and when I increase the input size by 100 times, the output increases by 10000 times. These outputs suggest a quadratic time function and `O(n squared)`.

Here is my full code:

```
import timeit
def create_list_with_concat(n):
    l = []
    for i in range(n):
        l = l + [i]

t1 = timeit.Timer("create_list_with_concat(100)", "from __main__ import 
create_list_with_concat")
print("concat ",t1.timeit(number=1)*1000, "milliseconds")
t1 = timeit.Timer("create_list_with_concat(1000)", "from __main__ 
import create_list_with_concat")
print("concat ",t1.timeit(number=1)*1000, "milliseconds")
# OUTPUT
# concat  0.05283101927489042 milliseconds
# concat  2.8588240093085915 milliseconds
```

Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: You realize there is a difference between `l = l + [i]`, and `l += [i]`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem in terms of the end result, there isn't. If you're alluding to something that's occurring at a lower-level, it would be nice if you were to share your knowledge.

Comment: @chb: but the question deals with time complexity, and in terms of time complexity, for lists there is a difference.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Sorry, was in the review queue and hadn't seen that you'd posted an answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The time complexity is not `O(N)`

The time complexity of the concat operation for two lists, A and B, is `O(A + B)`. This is because you aren't adding to one list, but instead are creating a whole new list and populating it with elements from both A and B, requiring you to iterate through both.

Therefore, doing the operation `l = l + [i]` is `O(len(l))`, leaving you with `N` steps of doing an `N` operation, resulting in an overall complexity of `O(N^2)`

You are confusing concat with the `append` or `extend` function, which doesn't create a new list but adds to the original. If you used those functions, your time complexity would indeed be `O(N)`

An additional note:

The notation `l = l + [i]` can be confusing because intuitively it seems like `[i]` is simply being added to the existing `l`. This isn't true!

`l + [i]` builds a entirely new list and then has `l` point to that list.

On the other hand `l += [i]` modifies the original list and behaves like `extend`

Comment: `l += [i]` should really just be `l.append(x)`

Comment: I just wanted to highlight the difference between `l += [i]` and `l = l + [i]`

Answer (score 3):

> Here is my thought process: I know that the concat operator is *O(k)* where *k* is the size of the list being added to the original list. Since the size of *k* is always 1 in this case because we are adding one character lists at a time, the concat operation takes 1 step.

This assumption is *incorrect*. If you write:

```
l + [i]
```

you construct a new list, this list will have *m+1* elements, with *m* the number of elements in `l`, given a list is implemented like an array, we know that constructing such list will take *O(m)* time. We then assign the *new* list to `l`.

So that means that the total number of steps is:

```
 n
---
\              2
/    O(m) = O(n )
---
m=0
```

so the time complexity is *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*.

You can however boost performance, by using `l += [i]`, or even faster `l.append(i)`, where the *amortize cost* is, for both `l += [i]` and `l.append(i)` *O(1)*, so then the algorithm is *O(n)*, the `l.append(i)` will however likely be a bit faster because we save on constructing a new list, etc.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: yes that correct, but after rereading, I realize the wording might be a bit "misleading", will edit.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> spam = []
>>> eggs = spam
>>> spam += [1]
>>> eggs
[1]
>>> spam = []
>>> eggs = spam
>>> spam = spam + [1]
>>> eggs
[]
```

There's a difference in complexity between mutating a list and making a new one.